# Import CSV to MySQL database using PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I'm trying to create a form which is sql injection safe where you can upload a CSV file to a MySQL database. The code I have is below however it echo's the data in the csv in the browser but doesn't insert the data into the database.

```
<?php
require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
$user = new USER();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $session = $_SESSION['user_session'];
        //upload file
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
            echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
            readfile($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
        }
        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
        $stmt = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO main(
                first_name,
                last_name,
                info1,
                info2,
                info3,
                info4,
                info5,
                info6,
                info7,
                info8) VALUES(
                ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $stmt->bindparam(1, $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(6, $data[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(7, $data[6], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(8, $data[7], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(9, $data[8], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindparam(10, $data[9], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: where is `$stmt->bindParam(1` ? You can't start at `2`.

Comment: I'm assuming `runQuery()` does a prepare.

Comment: Updated but still nothing - see question again for update

Comment: `readfile` does just that: output text to the browser. -- Also just `->execute($data)` would have been simpler than lots of `->bindParam` calls.

Comment: @mario Thank you mario, I removed all the `->bindParam` and just used `->execute($data)`. Works fine now :).

Answer (score -1):

Removed all of the `->bindParam` and replaced with `->execute($data)`.